# Переменная name в javascript. Что в ней особенного?

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему такое происходит в JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что существует глобальное свойство `name`, которое не только имеет строковый тип, но ещё и сохраняется между перезагрузками окна. Объявление `var name` в глобальной области игнорируется поскольку такое свойство уже есть.

Если хочется иметь глобальную переменную `name`, не являющуюся свойством окна, то можно объявить её через `let`:

```js
let name = 42
console.log(name + 1)
```

Если хочется воспроизвести проблему с name более явным способом, можно использовать такой код:

```js
~function () {
  with ({
    _x: "",
    get x() { return this._x },
    set x(x) { this._x = "" + x },
    [Symbol.unscopables]: { _x: true },
  }) {
    var x = 10, y = 10
    console.log(x+1, y+1) // 101 11
  }
}()
```

Answer (score 4):

Потому что у `window` уже есть строковое свойство `name`, и вы его задаёте.

Без функции, а просто в "начале скрипта", такие переменные - это ключи объекта `window`.

Если то же самое делать внутри какой-то функции, то будет работать как и ожидается.